# How to do block indentation in kate?

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5, kate

Question is pretty self-explanatory.

How to do block indentation in kate ([KDE Advanced Text Editor](https://kate-editor.org/))?

Comment: Ctrl+I - Use this to indent a selected block of text.You can configure whether tabs should be honored and used or replaced with spaces, in the configuration dialog. Source [download.xqy](https://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=veuviqxg4q2xtqi4&number=2)

Comment: Thanks David. Post the answer so I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl+I does it as commented by @DavidPostill
For removing indentation, Ctrl+Shift+I does the job.

Comment: Would be nice if this useful tip was findable in the Kate manual under keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Would be nice if this useful tip was findable in the Kate manual under keyboard shortcuts.